# How to rotate 3D points around arbitrary line (not passing through origin)?

Tags: python, 3d, rotation

I am trying to rotate point around arbitrary line("axis") using angle.

I am currently using rotational matrix as described here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Axis_and_angle

But it seems that the points are rotated around line passing through origin. In other words, it is rotating around line with correct direction, but in different location. Meaning that the points rotate correctly, but with different magnitude(angle) as the line closer to then thatn it should be.

Is it possible to calculate the offset into the matrix?
I could transalte all of the data including the rotation line to the origin. But than I would have to translate them back to the original rotated space.